# Cardinalities of power sets, $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Does there exist a set $X$ so that $|\mathcal{P}(X)|=|\Bbb{N}|$?

What about $|\mathcal{P}(X)|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

I'm pretty sure that the answer is no for the first one, and yes for the second one ($\Bbb{N}$), but I can't figure out how to prove these assertions. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint(s)**:For the first one, if you had $\lvert \mathcal P(X)\rvert=\lvert {\bf N}\rvert$, what could you say about $\lvert X\rvert$?

For the second one, notice first that $\lvert {\bf R}\rvert=\lvert [0,1]\rvert$. Now, consider the binary expansions of real numbers in $[0,1]$. How many real numbers have ambiguous binary expansions?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great hints without too much given away!